# Unable to install a extension from Download Manager

Tags: php, windows, magento, xampp

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I'm running my web site with Magento CE 1.4.2.0.

I wants to install the following extension in my site http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/vs-infinite-ajax-scrolling.html

i tried to install it but its giving the following error.

```
WARNING: channel "connect.magentocommerce.com/community" has updated its protocols, use "channel-update connect.magentocommerce.com/community" to update
downloading VS_Ajaxscrolling-1.0.0.tgz ...
Starting to download VS_Ajaxscrolling-1.0.0.tgz (41,899 bytes)
. . . . . . . . . ...done: 41,899 bytes
ERROR: failed to mkdir \var\www\magento14\app\code\community\VS\Ajaxscroll\Block
```

Please help me why its giving like this ?

And i'm using Magento Connect 1.0 only, if i tried to use Magento Connect 2.0 its giving the following error

```
Invalid package identifier provided: http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/VS_Ajaxscrolling
```

Why i'm getting this error ?

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: does your user account have the rights to create directories in that location. I doubt it unless you are root

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply @RiggsFolly ... I'm using admin user

Comment: "user account" is misleading.  The web server runs as a different user, usually "apache" or "http", which must have write access.  Do you know how to grant the right access on your server?  What OS is it using?

Comment: @clockworkgeek i'm running this with XAMPP on Windows. its my localhost.

Comment: I don't have the experience for that.  Hopefully someone will post a full answer explaining how to grant accesses.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I just replaced the magento/downloader folder of Magento 1.4.2  with the "downloader" folder from Magento 1.9.3.2 and extension got properly installed without any error. Hope this works for anybody else who faces similar issue.